# Simplifying expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, pattern-matching, expression-manipulation, semantic-matching

Let's define a function $\Omega(x,y)$

```
r1 = Sqrt[(x - 0.5)^2 + y^2];
r2 = Sqrt[(x + 0.5)^2 + y^2];
p1 = 1/r1^3 + λ/r2^3;
q1 = 1/2*(1/r1^3 - λ/r2^3);
Ax = -y*p1;
Ay = x*p1 - q1;
Ω = (x*Ay - y*Ax) + 1/2*(x^2 + y^2);
```

Now I want to obtain the first and the second derivatives of $\Omega$ at the most simplified expressions. After conducting the calculations by hand I derived

$\Omega_x = x + 2xp_1 - q1 + 3y^2q2 - 3x(x^2 + y^2)p_2 + 6x^2q_2 - 3xs_2$

$\Omega_y = y + 2yp_1 + 3xyq_2 - 3y(x^2 + y^2)p_2$

where

```
p2 = (1/r1^5 + λ/r2^5);
q2 = 1/2*(1/r1^5 - λ/r2^5);
s2 = 1/4*(1/r1^5 + λ/r2^5);
```

I tried to obtain the same results using Mathematica with

```
Ωx = D[Ω, x];
Ωy = D[Ω, y];

rule = {Sqrt[(x - 0.5)^2 + y^2] -> r1, 
Sqrt[(x + 0.5)^2 + y^2] -> r2, 
(1/r1^3 + λ/r2^3) -> p1, 1/2*(1/r1^3 - λ/r2^3) -> 
q1, (1/r1^5 + λ/r2^5) -> p2, 1/2*(1/r1^5 - λ/r2^5) -> 
q2, 1/4*(1/r1^5 + λ/r2^5) -> s2};

FullSimplify[Ωx] /. rule
FullSimplify[Ωy] /. rule
```

Unfortunately the program fails to provide the same elegant expressions obtained by hand. Is there a way to achieve this with Mathematica? For the derivatives of the second order the calculations are much more complicated and therefore I need the program to compute them in simplified form.

```
Ωxx = D[Ωx, x];
Ωxy = D[Ωx, y];
Ωyy = D[Ωy, y];
```

So, my question is how to obtain the expressions of the three second order derivatives in a simplified form as the ones, derived by hand regarding the first order derivatives?

Comment: Where's the definition of `r10` and `r20`?

Comment: @xzczd Oops! See my edit.

Comment: I'm afraid your result by hand is wrong: `Clear[p1, q1, p2, q2, s2, r1, r2]; rule = {(x - 0.5)^2 + y^2 -> r1, (x + 0.5)^2 + y^2 -> 
   r2, 1/r1^3 + \[Lambda]/r2^3 -> p1, 1/2 (1/r1^3 - \[Lambda]/r2^3) -> q1, 
  1/r1^5 + \[Lambda]/r2^5 -> p2, 1/2 (1/r1^5 - \[Lambda]/r2^5) -> q2, 
  1/4 (1/r1^5 + \[Lambda]/r2^5) -> s2};

Simplify[
   D[\[CapitalOmega], x] == x + (2*x*p1 - q1) + (3*y^2*q2 - 3*x*(x^2 + y^2)*p2) + 
             (6*x^2*q2 - 3*x*s2) //. Reverse /@ rule /. x -> 1 /. y -> 2]`

Comment: @xzczd No, the rule had a mistake! Check this: `Clear[p1, q1, p2, q2, s2, r1, r2]; rule = {Sqrt[(x - 0.5)^2 + y^2] -> 
   r1, Sqrt[(x + 0.5)^2 + y^2] -> r2, 1/r1^3 + λ/r2^3 -> p1, 
  1/2 (1/r1^3 - λ/r2^3) -> q1, 1/r1^5 + λ/r2^5 -> p2, 
  1/2 (1/r1^5 - λ/r2^5) -> q2, 1/4 (1/r1^5 + λ/r2^5) -> s2}; Simplify[
 D[Ω, x] == 
     x + (2*x*p1 - q1) + (3*y^2*q2 - 
        3*x*(x^2 + y^2)*p2) + (6*x^2*q2 - 3*x*s2) //. 
    Reverse /@ rule /. x -> 1 /. y -> 2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pattern matching of *Mathematica* isn't semantic but syntactic, so your replacement rules won't apply to the expression unless the `FullForm` of them matches. For more information you may want to read [this](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v7i3/features/harris/). (Sadly the package given in that page isn't strong enough yet and hasn't been updated for years.)

Since what you want is to simplify the second order derivatives, I modified the `rule` to make it more general:

```
Clear[r1, r2, p1, p2, q1, q2]
rule = {Sqrt[(x - 0.5)^2 + y^2] -> r1, 
   Sqrt[(x + 0.5)^2 + y^2] -> r2, (1/r1^n + λ/r2^n) -> p[n], 
   1/2*(1/r1^n - λ/r2^n) -> q[n]};

patt = r1 | r2;
rulemid = (a : patt)^n_ :> a[n];

replace = Simplify[# /. MapAt[#^2 &, rule, {1 ;; 2, All}] /. 
       s : (patt^2)^Rational[_, 2] :> Simplify[s, r1 > 0 && r2 > 0] /. 
      rulemid /. (First@
           Solve[Equal @@@ #, Union@Cases[#, patt[_], Infinity]] &@(rule[[3 ;; 4]] /. 
           rulemid) /. n -> -n /. (a : patt)[n] :> a[n_])] &;


replace@Ωx
(* -3. (0. + x^3 p[5] + x (-0.333333 - 0.666667 p[3] + 
   (0.25 + y^2) p[5]) + 0.333333 q[3] - 2. x^2 q[5] - 1. y^2 q[5]) *)
replace@Ωy
(* y (1 + 2 p[3] - 3 x^2 p[5] - 3 y^2 p[5] + 3 x q[5]) *)
```